# Android Sqlite return nothing when no value found

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am using this method to call query that will search videoname from sqlite database. In return am getting Value of Row_id_2 when videoname exist but when no video name found am getting nothing. Please let me know what should i do ? i want some event if nothing found.. No errors no Warnings.

```
public String seeVideoEntry(String VideoName) {


Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.query(Table_Name_2, new String[] {
Row_Id_2, Row_VideoName, Row_VideoCapturedTime, Row_VideoUrl,
Row_VideoDate, Row_VideoUri }, Row_VideoName + "=?",
new String[] { VideoName }, null, null, null, null);

try {
if (cursor != null) {
cursor.moveToFirst();
Log.e("Test1", VideoName);

}

} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Row_Id_2));

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the [`moveToFirst` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/AbstractCursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29):

> This method will return false if the cursor is empty.

You must check the return value of `moveToFirst()`:

```java
public String seeVideoEntry(String videoName) {
    Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.query(Table_Name_2,
                                      new String[] { Row_Id_2 },
                                      Row_VideoName + "=?",
                                      new String[] { videoName },
                                      null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        return cursor.getString(0);
    } else {
        return "not found";
    }
}
```

Comment: means instead of
`return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Row_Id_2));`
i need to use 
`return cursor.moveToFirst();`